# An unfamiliar equation in aerodynamics book

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Exploring the chapter dedicated to the conservation of momentum in fluids, I came across an equation for stress tensor: $$\tau_{xx}=2\mu\,\frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x}-\frac 2 3  \mu \, (\nabla\cdot\vec {V})$$
It’s said to connect the component of tensor $\tau$ perpendicular to a stressed surface with the projection of velocity ($V_x$ is often denoted as $u$) and dynamic viscosity $\mu$, but I can’t understand. Can anybody, please, explain it, and also where the coefficients come from? And if possible, use a sketch of a unit volume.

Comment: See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 1.  This is the x component of the viscous portion of the stress tensor on a plane oriented perpendicular to the x direction.  Everything you want to know about this is presented in the reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clarifies everything!